# Tapku library -what is the date format in day view

Tags: iphone, date-format, tapku

I am using Tapku library in my application. While displaying day view, I am getting the `startDate` and `endDate` values from my server. What is the date format used in Tapku library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format for tapku library is-

```
[YYYY-MM-DD hour:minute:second]
```

e.g.
@"2011-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"

for more info visit this Link- [tapku Library](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers#the-code)

Comment: i am using the same format. 
TKCalendarDayEventView *eventViewFirst = [TKCalendarDayEventView eventViewWithFrame:CGRectZero
id:nil startDate:(NSDate*)@"2012-12-12 16:30:00 +0000"  endDate:[NSDate date] title:[inputDictionary objectForKey:@"eventName"]
 location:[inputDictionary objectForKey:@"eventLocation"]];  


But app is crashed. Below is the log message.
-[__NSCFConstantString dateInformation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c8afc
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString dateInformation]:

Comment: My time zone is +5.30. The 14.30 is suppose to show as 2.30 according to my time zone. But now its showing as 8.00PM.
Where i have to set the time zone in tapkulibrary? Its very urgent. Pls help me.