# Date format of Tapku Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, date-format, tapku

In the API , the selected day format is like `2013-11-01T23:00:00%2B0000`

But my date format is like this: `2013-11-01T23:00:00+0000`

To convert, I have used below code:

```
NSString *plus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [timeStamp substringToIndex:[timeStamp length]-5], @"%2B0000"];
```

Instead of (+) the unicode of plus which is (%2B).

But when I select the day from Tapku calender, I receive the error which says **date format is wrong**. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7):

```
           NSDate *tempDate=toDate;

           NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"];



           [periodOfInspectionToTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:d]]];
           toDate=[df dateFromString:periodOfInspectionToTextField.text];
```

Comment: But in the api that im getting data the formate is utc . And when it is like this  **2013-11-01T23:00:00+0000**  I dont have problem. But the api formate doesnt accept (+)plus that I have. So i have to use the unicode of (+)plus. In this situation , Tapku doesnt accept. That is the problem. Am I clear?

Comment: [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z"] if you are set the formatter like this you will get answer like this " 2013-11-08T05:30:00 GMT+5:30" if you know more about date format you just refer these two links http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/ and http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/nsdateformatter-format-strings

Comment: I have already gotten the date formate like this. But my problem is that I need to get like this: 2013-11-01T23:00:00%2B0000 for the formate of my api. But in this case tapku calender doesnt recognize this is a date. ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the dateformat of tapku which is below:-

```
   [YYYY-MM-DD hour:minute:second];
```

Also follow this link for more details.

[Tapku library -what is the date format in day view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848719/tapku-library-what-is-the-date-format-in-day-view)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to unescape the date string from the API to remove the percent escapes:

```
NSString *dateString = [@"2013-11-01T23:00:00%2B0000" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This will give a date string of `2013-11-01T23:00:00+0000`. Then you need to parse this string into a `NSDate` object:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzzz"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: In this situation date is nil

Comment: @santa I've just run the code in Xcode and [here's the output I get](http://cl.ly/SKts). The `date` variable is not `nil`.

Comment: sorry , i made a mistake for this it was nil. But I have already had this result. the api formate doesnt accept this formate. In the api formate instead of ** (+ )** plus I need to show **( %2B )** this character . %2B is the unicode of +(plus).